# Javascript replace with RegExp repeating itself?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, repeat

I am trying to replace any occurrence of [start] or [end] in a string defined by user input. I want this to be case-insensitive so it would also replace [Start], [STARt], etc.

An example input string is

```
var eventLabel = "BPY [start]";
```

Here is what I am trying

```
var result = eventLabel.replace(new RegExp("[start]", "gi"), "replaced");
```

Here is the contents of result after the replace

```
BPY [replacedreplacedreplacedreplacedreplaced]
```

It is inside of a loop however, when I alert the result directly after the first replace it is like that. It's also leaving the brackets there but only replacing the contents which is strange.

Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `[` symbol because `[` is a special meta character in regex which means the start of a character class. To match both `[start]` or `[end]` strings, don't forget to put them inside a group like below.

```
var result = eventLabel.replace(new RegExp("\\[(?:start|end)\\]", "gi"), row['startTime']);
```

OR

```
var result = eventLabel.replace(/\[(?:start|end)\]/gi, row['startTime']);
```

Comment: There's no good reason for `new RegExp` here, and definitely a good reason *not* to use it. Instead: `var result = eventLabel.replace(/\[(?:start|end)\]/gi, row['startTime']);`

Answer (score 1):

`[start]` means "replace any one of `s`, `t`, `a`, or `r`".

You'll need to escape the brackets:

```
var result = eventLabel.replace(new RegExp("\\[(start|end)\\]", "gi"), "replaced");
```